# Check if a Blender class has a property?

Tags: python, scripting, grease-pencil, properties

I need to check if a Blender class (In my case, `GPencilLayer`) has a certain property before executing some code.

I have tried:

```
hasattr(bpy.types.GPencilLayer, the_name_of_the_property)
```

But it doesnt work. For example:

```
hasattr(bpy.types.GPencilLayer, "hide") # returns False
```

But "hide" is a property of [GPencilLayer](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GPencilLayer.html#bpy.types.GPencilLayer.hide)

So Im kinda lost. I know (well, I think) that I could call the same code with a GPencilLayer object. But in my code, is not guaranted that exists already a GPencilLayer in the scene, so I can't always "grab an instance" and I would prefer to check it with the class.

Any idea?

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this little function:

```
def has_property(btype, propname):
    for prop in btype.bl_rna.properties:
        if prop.identifier == propname:
            return True
    return False

# test
btype = bpy.types.GPencilLayer
prop = 'hide'
print(btype, 'has property "' + prop + '":', has_property(btype, prop))

# >>> <class 'bpy.types.GPencilLayer'> has property "hide": True
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! Thank you so much friend, much appreciated!